# Problema con fechas vb6 y oracle

Tags: oracle, vb6

Tengo una aplicación de reportes desarrollada en VB6 y base de datos Oracle 8.
Por necesidades que fueron surgiendo, fui metiendo nuevos campos y funciones que complicaron la consulta. La última es que se necesitaba listar por fecha de producción, siendo esta entre las 7:00:00 am del día consultado y las 06:59:00 del día próximo ( subsiguiente ) .
O sea, si pido un listado con fecha 30/05/2018 , cargo un listview con los datos comprendidos entre las 7:00:00 am del 30/05/2018 y las 06:59:00 am del 31/05/2018 .
Como veran en el código, funciona correctamente.
Lo que necesito ahora, es que con la misma consulta, se escriba en el listview la fecha 30/05/2018 , o sea la fecha de producción, teniendo en cuenta que la consulta puede ser de varios días , o sea debería visualizar en el listview cada día de producción con la fecha unificada.
Espero se entienda la necesidad. Copio parte del código que utilizo :

```
    If c_porfecha Then
        Dim cformato1 As String
        Dim cformato2 As String

        cformato1 = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss a.m."
        cformato2 = "nls_date_language=american"

        fec1 = CStr(var_fecha1) & " 07:00:00 a.m."
        fec2 = DateAdd("d", 1, DTPicker2.value) & " 06:59:00 a.m."

        If cadenita <> "" Then
            cadenita = cadenita & "AND TS_CREACION BETWEEN TO_DATE('" & fec1 & "','" & cformato1 & "','" & cformato2 & "') " & _
                                  "AND TO_DATE('" & fec2 & "','" & cformato1 & "','" & cformato2 & "') "
            titulo_reporte = titulo_reporte & "desde el " & label1(3) & " hasta el " & label1(4)
            Else
            cadenita = cadenita & " TS_CREACION BETWEEN TO_DATE('" & fec1 & "','" & cformato1 & "','" & cformato2 & "') " & _
                                  "AND TO_DATE('" & fec2 & "','" & cformato1 & "','" & cformato2 & "') "

            titulo_reporte = titulo_reporte & "Todos los Registros desde el " & label1(3) & " hasta el " & label1(4)
        End If

        cformato1 = ""
        cformato2 = ""
        con_where = True
    End If



       Set RsListado = oradatabase.dbcreatedynaset(cadenita, 0&)

        If Not (RsListado.BOF And RsListado.EOF) = True Then
            RsListado.MoveLast
            a1 = RsListado.RecordCount
            ProgressBar1.Min = 0
            ProgressBar1.Max = a1
            RsListado.MoveFirst

            For b1 = 1 To a1
                Label3 = Str(a1)
                ProgressBar1.value = b1
                label7 = CLng((ProgressBar1.value * 100) / ProgressBar1.Max) & " %"
                Set subelemento = LvDatos.ListItems.Add(, CStr(RsListado!id) & "M", CStr(RsListado!id))
                subelemento.SubItems(1) = CStr(RsListado!SECTOR)
                subelemento.SubItems(2) = CStr(RsListado!AREA)
                subelemento.SubItems(3) = CStr(RsListado!ISLA)
                subelemento.SubItems(4) = Format(CDate(RsListado!fecha), "dd/mm/yyyy")
                subelemento.SubItems(5) = Trae_Op(RsListado!OP)
                RsListado.MoveNext
            Next
            If btnProcesar.Enabled = False Then btnProcesar.Enabled = True
        Else
            LvDatos.ListItems.Clear
            Label3 = "0"
            MsgBox "No existen datos !", vbCritical
            If btnProcesar.Enabled = True Then btnProcesar.Enabled = false
        End If

    If titulo_reporte = "Reporte de " Then titulo_reporte = "Reporte de Todos los Registros"
    Set subelemento = Nothing
    LvDatos.Sorted = False ' Con esto se ordena la lista :)

RsListado.Close
Set RsListado = Nothing
Set subelemento = Nothing
```

Comment: vos queres que aca subelemento.SubItems(4) = Format(CDate(RsListado!fecha), "dd/mm/yyyy") diga siempre la misma fecha?

Comment: no precisamente. Quisiera que si pido un listado desde el 25 de mayo al 27 de mayo, en el listview se carguen :
1) Los registros comprendidos entre las 07:00:00 am del 25 de mayo y los del 26 de mayo hasta las 06:59:00 con feha 25 de Mayo.
2) Los registros comprendidos entre las 07:00:00 am del 26 de mayo y los del 27 de mayo hasta las 06:59:00 con feha 26 de Mayo. 
3) Los registros comprendidos entre las 07:00:00 am del 27 de mayo y los del 28 de mayo hasta las 06:59:00 con feha 27 de Mayo.

Comment: O si pido solamente los registros del 28 de Mayo  se listen los registros comprendidos entre las 07:00:00 am del 28 de mayo y los del 29 de mayo hasta las 06:59:00 ... con feha 28 de Mayo.

Comment: Aclara la ptegunta entonces pq yo la verdad no te entiendo. El problema es la query o la vista?

Comment: si, disculpas, el problema sería la vista, la query trae lo que necesito, el tema es como logro modificar ( unificar) las fechas ... con que se muestre ya me sirve

Comment: para eso vas a necesitar mostrar como vienen los datos en tu recordset y como queres que queden. modifica la pregunta con esa informacion, lo que estas diciendo no deberia ser nada complicado.

Comment: y si el problema es la vista, oracle no tiene nada que ver aca (como no tenia que ver visual studio)

Comment: En el código que incluí con la pregunta, está primero la query o consulta y más abajo la apertura del recordset y llenado del listview mediante un bucle for .. quizás solo viste una parte ?

Comment: Lo lei todo. Lo que digo, es que si los datos vienen bien, oracle no tiene nada que ver con tu problema. Tu problema es una vez obtenido el recordset. Y para ayudarte con eso, necesitamos ver tu recordset, y un ejemplo claro de lo que queres de salida. Esto es un problema de cortes de control (de aca a aca usar una fecha, luego usar otra, luego otra, y etc).

Comment: Hola si, está claro. Hago referencia a oracle porque en mi desconocimiento, pense que quizas había algun camino modificando la consulta. Los datos llegan perfectos , lo que no se es cual seria una forma optima de volcar los datos a un listview de vb6 ya modificados, o sea, como hacer para detectar y modificar los registros del día siguiente con horario entre las 00:00 y 06:59 y asi poder modificarlos antes de volcarlos. En el código muestro como tomo el recordset y como lo vuelco linea a linea.

Comment: Si pero no tenemos un ejemplo de datos ni de la salida esperada. y asi es dificil ayudarte.

Comment: lo que necesito modificar , es el dato que recojo de subelemento.SubItems(4) = Format(CDate(RsListado!fecha), "dd/mm/yyyy") , calculo que de alguna forma tengo que ir viendo que si la hora de este registro es entre las 00:01 y 06:59 la retraso 1 día , ese registro es del tipo DATE en Oracle, trae la fecha en formato americano con el AM y PM ...

Comment: te veo en el [chat]. No pareces entender que sin datos es dificil saber como ayudarte a solucionar el problema. y lo que me estas escribiendo, lo escribi ya en el primer comentario